# Using Parseval's identity to show that $\frac{\pi^2}{8}=1+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{5^2}+\frac{1}{7^2}+...$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, fourier-analysis

By considering the Fourier sine series on the interval $[0,\pi]$ for $f(x)=1$, show that $$\frac{\pi^2}{8}=1+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{5^2}+\frac{1}{7^2}+...$$

I am having trouble computing the Fourier sine series, which will have the form $$Sf(x)=\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k\cos\left(\frac{k\pi x}{L}\right), \ \ k\geq 1.$$
I have computed that $a_0=1$ and $a_n=0$, using $$a_0=\frac{1}{L}\int_{-L}^{L} f(x) \ dx,  \ \ a_k=\frac{1}{L}\int_{-L}^{L} f(x)\cos\left(\frac{k\pi x}{L}\right) \ dx,$$ where $L$ denotes half a period. Once the correct Fourier series is calculated, showing the result using $$\Vert{f}\Vert^2_{w}=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} A^2_j\Vert\phi_j\Vert^2_w,$$
should not be so hard.

---

I have found the Fourier sine series, $$Sf(x)=\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin((2j-1)x)}{(2j-1)}.$$ But I having trouble proving the identity in the title. Using Parseval's identity provided above, I get that $$\Vert f\Vert^2_w=1, \ \ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} A^2_j\Vert\phi_j\Vert^2_w=\frac{8}{\pi}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2j-1)^2},$$ which does not show the required result (out by a factor of $\pi$). Note: I took the weight function, $w$, to be $1$. Please help.

Comment: The Fourier sine series should be a series in _sine_, not cosine. There should also be no constant term in the series.

Comment: Crap. Is this because we are considering an odd function?

Comment: No, it's because the question is asking you to compute the sine series. Note that $f$ is neither even nor odd as it stands, so you need to make an odd extension before computing the coefficients.

Comment: I think you want the function as $f(x)=1$ for $0<x<\pi$ and $f(x)=-1$ for $0>x>-\pi$. You should get a sine series $\sum_1^\infty a_k\sin kx$. But, if you ask me, complex Fourier series with terms $e^{inx}$ are easier to work with.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown Yep, I agree with your extension of the function. You have forced it to be odd. How do I now calculate the Fourier series? For instance, do I now consider the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$? But then what value should I take for $f$? I very much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you're looking for a series of sines, not cosines here. I'm guessing you went for cosines because the function is even, like cosine. But the interval you're looking at here is $[0,\pi]$, not $[-\pi,\pi]$, and in fact in this interval it is the sine function that is symmetric (because $\sin(\pi-x)=\sin x$).

Your Fourier series should then look something like $\displaystyle \sum a_k\sin\left(\frac{k\pi x}{L}\right)$, where the $a_k$ are instead given by
$$a_k=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi f(x)\sin\left(\frac{k\pi x}{L}\right)\,dx$$
(so integrating over just half of the interval, from $0$ to $\pi$).

Another way to get this same series is to instead extend $f$ by defining $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&x>0\\-1&x<0\end{cases}$$
on the entire interval $[-\pi,\pi]$. Now you can use the form of the Fourier series you have in your question; since the function is odd, its series will have only sines. On the interval $[0,\pi]$ it is just equal to $1$ still, though.

Comment: Thanks, with you help I have found the correct Fourier sine series: $$Sf(x)=\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin((2j-1)x)}{(2j-1)}.$$ Could you please assist me in concluding the problem using Parseval's identity provided above? Using this, I get that $$\Vert f\Vert^2_w=1, \ \ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} A^2_j\Vert\phi_j\Vert^2_w=\frac{8}{\pi}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2j-1)^2},$$ which does not show the required result... Note: I took the weight function, $w$, to be $1$.

Comment: @JulianAngussmith : isn't the integral of $f^{2}$ over [0,$\pi$] equal to $\pi$? I think that's what you are missing.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you a lot! Can I also ask, why does $w=1$?